# Can we run multiple Selenium code to access different websites by creating multiple desktops in the same PC?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, browser-automation

I'm working on automation through Python and Selenium, I want to run multiple codes at a time to access the different sites (Some times the same site). Usually, I'll run the code in the Jupyter notebook. If I run it I couldn't do any other work in the system, since it's utilizing keyboard and Mouseclicks.

So is there any possibility to run the code on the same laptop or PC by creating multiple desktop options?

Comment: You might be able run multiple code if you use beautifulsoup. But provide your code so that we will a better understanding of what you are doing?

Comment: Run in headless mode with pre-assigned clicks and input. You should also look into running selenium concurrently